# after subscribing endpoint to token is this disabled then how to detect in aws sns

Tags: notifications, amazon-sns

I added one token in aws sns , generated platform end point for that. and subscribed that end point to Topic. now again reinstall app , we got another token for same device. if We not subscribe that  token to topic then notification sent for topic is not received

Why we need to resubscribe for same device?

and if we subscribed that to topic then topic will contain 2 endpoint subscribed one is new and other is old how to find that old disable /unused endpoint , to unsubscribe from topic

This also causing multiple endpoint for same device get subscribe causing slow on notification, how we can prevent this , any way to remove unused and unsubscribe endpoint from topic

Can we get aws sns mobile pushnotification without device token?

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the app, the phone creates a new token that must be re-registered. This is not AWS creating a new token for the device.

I'd recommend looking over the [best practices for push notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-notifications-best-practices.html).

The recommended way to remove subscriptions pointing to stale endpoints is to use [mobile app events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/application-event-notifications.html#application-event-notifications-sdk) - in particular, "Delivery Failure", which will tell you which endpoint and subscription the delivery failed for, so that you can remove it.